# Solving five simultaneous equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

so given five simultaneous equations,

$x+y+z=10$

$xy=4$

$2x=t+uy$

$2y=t+ux$

$2z=t$

How should I go about solving this? It's part of a question on Lagrange multipliers that requires me to find the minimum to the equation $f(x,y,z)$ = $x^2+y^2+z^2$. I've been banging my head trying to figure this one out. Every time I try to substitute one of the variable in the other equation, I run into the issue of `t` and `u`. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What are $t$ and $u$? Parameters? Are you solving for $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate more on the original minimization problem? You have to minimize $f$ subject to which constraint?

Comment: @user496634 Yes they are perimeters. I am solving for _(x,y,z)_ that that will give the minimum value for _f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2)_.

Comment: @weee Minimize f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2) with constraints x+y+z=10 and xy=4.

Answer (score 2):

$2x=2z+uy$,

$2y=2z+ux$,

$2x^2-2xz=2y^2-2yz$

$2x^2-2x(10-x-y)=2y^2-2y(10-x-y)$

$2x^2-20x+2x^2+2xy=2y^2-20y+2xy+2y^2$

$4x^2-20x=4y^2-20y={64\over x^2}-{80\over x}$

$4x^4-20x^3=64-80x$

$0=x^4-5x^3+20x-16=(x-1)(x^3-4x^2-4x+16)=(x-1)(x^2-4)(x-4)$

Comment: Note to would-be editors: OP wrote, "Any help or insight would be appreciated." OP didn't write, "Please write out a detailed solution, explaining every step along the way." So, I done what OP said to do. You want to disobey OP and write out a complete solution, then post your own, and keep your mitts off mine.

Comment: Well, you just spilled a bunch of uncommented equations all over the place, which can certainly considered a help or insight. I just tried to clarify things a little. If you are pleased with your, in my opinion, messy presentation that's fine with me, no need to be rude.

Comment: @weee, I think calling my presentation "messy" is rude, not to mention inaccurate.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your input. You saved my sanity! Just for future reference, what is the guiding principle in solving for  simultaneous equations? How should I approach such questions?

Comment: The guiding principle is eliminate variables, one at a time, starting with the ones easiest to eliminate.

Comment: You have all been very gracious to me with your help. I hope that same gracefulness can also be shared with one another :)